# How do I Normalize two Vectors in Python?

Tags: python, vector, normalization

Create a function MeanDistance(v1,v2) that returns the normalized distance between
two vectors with elements between 0 and 1: The function should return 0 if the vectors
are the same, and 1 if they are maximally different. This function should be used to compute
the distance d between v1 and v2.

How do I go about doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the question is asking you to normalize the *vectors*.  It's asking you to normalize the *distance*.  To do that, calculate the distance between the two vectors using your favorite distance measure ([Euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), [Manhattan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance), etc.) and divide by a constant that represents the maximum distance that is possible.  The distance measure to use depends on your application (the ones I gave as examples are the most common).  The value of the constant also depends on your application (specifically, the limits of your co-ordinate space, which seem to be 0 and 1 for all dimensions).